# Doctrine manyToOne with default "empty" value causes attempted insert of empty entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to model an optional one to one relationship between two entities, which when there is no real value a default sentinel value is used instead.

The entities are (more or less) as follows:

Owning entity:

```
AcmeBundle\Entity\Issue:
  type: entity
  table: Issues
  repositoryClass: AcmeBundle\Entity\IssueRepository
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  manyToOne:
    story_1:
      targetEntity: \AcmeBundle\Entity\Story
    story_1a:
      targetEntity: \AcmeBundle\Entity\Story
    story_1b:
      targetEntity: \AcmeBundle\Entity\Story
```

Dependent entity:

```
AcmeBundle\Entity\Story:
  type: entity
  table: Stories
  repositoryClass: AcmeBundle\Entity\StoryRepository
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    title:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: false
    etc...
```

The Issue is created using an Entity Form.  The Story entity has an Entity Form as well, on which there is a ModelDataTransformer which handles replacing an empty Story from the form into the sentinel Story.

What is **supposed** to happen is that when the form is submitted with empty stories, the ModelDataTransformer swaps them with the sentinel (which it does, verified in debugger), the FormHandler persists the Issue and flushes it all to the database.

The problem is that when performing the flush, instead of using the sentinel value, it is trying to insert completely empty Story entities and causing IntegrityErrors because empty Story entities are not allowed.

I've stepped through the entire *EntityManager->flush()* process, during which it retains perfectly the proper sentinel data.  But for some reason just before actually performing the inserts it swaps it all out for empty Story data and comes crashing to a burning halt.

For reference, I'm including snippets from the DataTransformer and FormHandler, just in case I'm doing something completely wrong there.  None of this makes any sense, it all seems like everything set up correctly, and yet it fails.

DataTransformer (snippet):

```
public function reverseTransform($value)
{
    if ($value === null || $value->getId() === null) {
        return $this->om
            ->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Story')
            ->getNullStory();
    }

    return $value;
}
```

FormHandler (snippet):

```
$t = $this->om->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Story')->getNullStory();
$this->issue->setStory1($t);
$this->issue->setStory1a($t);
$this->issue->setStory1b($t);
$this->om->flush();
```

Note that the FormHandler provided is the "screw it, just try and save a damn sentinel no matter what because I'm getting insanely frustrated" version.  I've tried several permutations of handling the setting of stories, including persisting the sentinel story before setting it on the issue, persisting the sentinel after setting it on the issue, even just not setting anything at all and letting Doctrine figure it out.  Every way I've tried ends up with the same result.

Hopefully I've provided enough information.  I opted for the snippets for brevity, but I can include the full code for anything if requested.